How to vary the stile along a line in QGIS
I currently have a project with many lines where in the symbology I have the offset controlled by an expression. However with this setup I can only produce a single offset value for each feature in my layer. What I would like is to have the offset of each feature start at one value and interpolate to another at the end of the feature. Is such a thing possible? The end goal is to enable transitions between different offsets. For example the first feature would have offset 1mm, then the second would start at 1mm and transition to 0mm, then the third feature would be all 0mm.
A simpler example of what I am trying to do is could I have it so that each line symbol for feature in a layer grows in size along it's length?

Using Geometry generator symbology you could try using a tapered buffer. function tapered_buffer
Creates a buffer along a line geometry where the buffer diameter varies evenly over the length of the line.

Let's see if I understand your question, have you tried the Interpolated Line symbology?

